# Select Option + Php + Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, jquery

Tengo un select option el cual depende de otro para poder mostrar los registros solicitados, el select llamado bascula tiene tres opciones dependiendo cual sea la elegida se manda una consulta mediante POST para obtener sus registros en el select llamado compuesto.

**Código de los select**

```
    <!-- Báscula -->
<div class="col-2">
    <h6 class="mb-4">Báscula:</h6>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="bascula" id="bascula" required>
        <option value="1" selected hidden>Selecciona una opción</option>
        <option value="Pigmentos 2" <?php if (isset($_POST['bascula'])) {
                                        if ($_POST['bascula'] == 'Pigmentos 2') {
                                            echo "selected";
                                        }
                                    } ?>> Pigmentos 2 </option>
        <option value="Pigmentos 3" <?php if (isset($_POST['bascula'])) {
                                        if ($_POST['bascula'] == 'Pigmentos 3') {
                                            echo "selected";
                                        }
                                    } ?>> Pigmentos 3 </option>
        <option value="Pigmentos 4" <?php if (isset($_POST['bascula'])) {
                                        if ($_POST['bascula'] == 'Pigmentos 4') {
                                            echo "selected";
                                        }
                                    } ?>> Pigmentos 4 </option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- Compuestos -->
<div class="col-2">
    <h6 class="mb-4">Compuesto:</h6>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="compuestos" id="compuestos" required>
        <option value="1" selected hidden>Selección 1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Información que mando al POST desde Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bascula").on('change', function () {
        $("#bascula option:selected").each(function () {
            bascula = $(this).val();
            $.post("datos.php", {
                bascula: bascula
            }, function (data) {
                $("#compuestos").html(data);
            });
        });
    });

});
```

**Código del envió por post**

```
$html = "";

if ($_POST['bascula'] == 'Pigmentos 2' || $_POST['compuestos'] == '') {
    $sqlComp = "SELECT Compuesto FROM [Pigmentos2].[dbo].[CopiaRegistraPeso] WHERE Bascula = 'Pigmentos 2' GROUP BY Compuesto";
    $resultComp = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlComp);

    while ($rowComp = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultComp, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $html = "    

        <option value = '$rowComp[Compuesto]' selected>$rowComp[Compuesto]</option>

        ";

        echo $html;
    }
}
```

Al dar clic sobre el botón consultar si muestra los resultados en la tabla de lo que estoy seleccionado, pero refresca toda la página lo que hace que pierda los registros del select compuestos y para volver a generar la consulta tengo que nuevamente seleccionar la opción de bascula.

**Tabla**

```
    <table id="example" class="records_list table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Compuesto</th>
                <th>Material</th>
                <th>Peso</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Hora</th>
                <th>Pesador</th>
                <th>Báscula</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <div id="tablaInfo">
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['input_consultar'])) {
                var_dump($_POST['compuestos']);
            ?>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $sqlPigment = "SELECT * FROM [Pigmentos2].[dbo].[CopiaRegistraPeso] WHERE CONVERT(date, Fecha, 103) >= '" . $_POST['input_fecha_inicial'] . "' AND CONVERT(date, Fecha, 103) <= '" . $_POST['input_fecha_final'] . "' AND Bascula = '" . $_POST['bascula'] . "' AND Compuesto = '" . $_POST['compuestos'] . "'  ORDER BY Fecha DESC";
                    $resultPigment = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlPigment);
    
                    while ($rowPigment = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultPigment)) {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $rowPigment['Compuesto']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $rowPigment['Material']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $rowPigment['Peso']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $rowPigment['Fecha']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $rowPigment['Hora']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $rowPigment['Pesador']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $rowPigment['Bascula']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
    
            <?php
                return false;
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </table>
```

Interfaz
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan apoyarme y sobre todo que haya podido ser clara con la problemática que presento, gracias.

Comment: Para que no recargue toda la página, debes vincular el botón 'Consultar' a una consulta AJAX que, en general, haga esto: 1) recupere la información en base a los parámetros de las listas de selección, 2) borre el contenido de la tabla [mediante  $("#tablaInfo tbody").empty()  ] y 3) recree el contenido de la tabla usando la información filtrada [mediante $("#tablaInfo tbody").append()   ]